# syslog-ng: Switch logs on demand

Tags: linux, syslog-ng

How can I tell syslog-ng that I would like to switch the logfiles.

I'm looking for a command or signal to tell syslog-ng to perform a logswitch. A search of the documentation and FAQ did not come up with a solution.

Answer (score 5):

It's `logrotate` which takes care of rotating logs. `logrotate -f` forces the log rotation even if logrotate think it is not needed. After that you can tell syslog-ng to reopen its logfiles with `killall -HUP syslog-ng` (or, quite likely, your logrotate will do that for you in its post-rotate hooks).